# Passing an ip address as a bash variable into ssh?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I have a python shell script, launcher.py which spits out an ip address
into a file called ipaddr.txt.

I need to use this single ip address which ipaddr.txt contains to connect to a host,
but for some reason ssh hangs when trying to get it to connect to the 
ip address fed into it.

First I run the script to put the ip address into the file (ipaddr.txt)

```
./launcher.py &&
```

Then I try to get ssh to connect to the ip address in question

```
uname="root@"
ip_addr=$uname"$(cat ipaddr.txt)" &&

ssh eval echo $ip_addr
```

An example result from echoing $ip_addr is:

```
root@45.55.43.11
```

For some reason ssh just hangs, and I am guessing that it has to do with me trying to pass in a bash variable as an argument into ssh, but I am not sure how to solve it. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `eval echo`? All you should need is `ssh $ip_addr`...

Comment: Sorry, on mobile and missed @l’L’l comment. I’ve deleted my answer as it was the same

Comment: Yup, just found out that the problem was that the script launcher.py was creating a droplet on digitalocean, however the hanging was just the droplet not being able to reply (since it was still being created). Leaving some time for the droplet to get fired up solved the problem.